# Averaging Multiple Arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have three 2x2 arrays, with each element filled with floats and `NaNs`. I want to average each element of the arrays, excluding the `NaNs` and then input this into a new array.

Is there any way of doing this without using a for loop and going through each individual element of each array and then using `np.Nanmean`?

I have millions of elements to check so this is exhausting the code.

Comment: How else could you do it without going through the whole array? Sorry if there is a way.

Comment: Doesn't using `np.Nanmean` require that you make a *new* array?  Computing the mean does not require gathering the values into a new array; you just need the sum of the non-NaN values & how many there are.

Comment: what do you mean "this is exhausting the code"?

Comment: At the moment I’m going through an element of each array using a for loop and averaging those values. Then I’m putting this value into a new array in the same location. Since I have millions of elements, this process is taking a long time to output a result. Is there a way to do this quicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind creating a new array, the following should be quicker than using for loops. Change the list of the 2x2 array in np.stack() with yours.

```
a1 = np.array([[np.nan, 0], [1, 2]])
a2 = np.array([[3, np.nan], [5, 6]])
a3 = np.array([[7, 8], [np.nan, 10]])
np.nanmean(np.stack([a1, a2, a3]), axis=0)
```

output:

```
array([[5., 4.],
       [3., 6.]])
```